# Pulling up and re-using historic data after a payment is made

Tags: cognito-forms

I see that with Entry Sharing it is possible for the data to be revisited by the form filler - but then I notice that if there is a payment attached to this form the data does not appear to be able to be revisited.

Is that right?

I want to use Cognito Forms for membership data for a club where an annual fee is due from each member - this fee may vary per member (according to their membership criteria) and may increase/decrease but the basic information - name address, status etc I would like to be able to be pulled from the original data (with the option for the member to edit it if necessary).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

When a form has a payment that has been paid the entry can't be edited as this could change the amount due for the form.

At the moment we do not have a way to edit an entry that has been submitted with a payment.

Comment: HI - thanks - it is not that I want to 'edit' the original entry - I want certain data (name etc) to be pulled from that entry to a new form - but I assume that is not possible?